# JavaScript .reduce() method not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dialog window that contains various form elements within a containing div. I want to create JSON string from all the form elements contained within the div.

To do so, I use the following statement

```
$("#dialogServiceItems").find("select, textarea, input").serializeArray();
```

This works well enough, but I am left with a result of

```
[{"name":"FrequentExtraItemID","value":"12"},{"name":"ServiceType","value":"Testing the service type"},{"name":"Vendor","value":"Some vendor"},{"name":"Cost","value":"100"},{"name":"Description","value":"A description"},{"name":"ExtraServiceID","value":"0"},{"name":"JobExtraID","value":"79"}]
```

I would like to end up with

```
{"FrequentExtraItemID":"12","ServiceType":"Testing the service type","Vendor":"Some vendor","Cost":"100","Description":"A description","ExtraServiceID":"0","JobExtraID":"79"}
```

So, I am using the JavaScript `reduce()` method like so:

```
var beforeReduce = $("#dialogServiceItems").find("select, textarea, input").serializeArray();
var afterReduce = beforeReduce.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) {
        if (currentIndex === 1) {
          var json = {};
          json[accumulator.name] = accumulator.value;
          return json;
        }
        accumulator[currentValue.name] = currentValue.value;
        return accumulator;
      });
```

But, the result is skipping the second element (ServiceType)

```
{"FrequentExtraItemID":"12","Vendor":"Some vendor","Cost":"100","Description":"A description","ExtraServiceID":"0","JobExtraID":"79"}
```

I'm not sure why it is skipping the second element.

I create an example Fiddle to illustrate the issue here: https://jsfiddle.net/x4r1neah/2/

Comment: index starts from 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than testing the index in the reduce loop, just pass the initial value in as the second argument. It will all be much easier to read and understand:

```js
let l = [{"name":"FrequentExtraItemID","value":"12"},{"name":"ServiceType","value":"Testing the service type"},{"name":"Vendor","value":"Some vendor"},{"name":"Cost","value":"100"},{"name":"Description","value":"A description"},{"name":"ExtraServiceID","value":"0"},{"name":"JobExtraID","value":"79"}]

let reduced = l.reduce((acc, {name, value}) => {
    acc[name] = value
    return acc
}, {}) // <-- pass in empty object for initial accumulator 

console.log(reduced)
```

Answer (score 1):

You `return json` which will blow away all the results of the accumulator on that iteration of the loop.

Remove your `if` statement entirely. You're also missing the initial accumulator value to reduce, so add

```
beforeReduce.reduce(function() {...}, {});
```

To clean the whole thing up and avoid mutating (mutating can be bad) and mutating function arguments (majority of the time bad), you can use some of the nice new ES6 shorthand and simply do:

```
beforeReduce.reduce((acc, {name, value}) => ({ ...acc, [name]: value }), {})
```

Comment: If he does that, `accumulator` will be `undefined` at the first iteration. He also needs to pass a second parameter to `reduce` to set an initial value.

Answer (score 1):

> But, the result is skipping the second element (ServiceType)

This happens because if there is no [initialValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

> A value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. Calling reduce() on an empty array without an initialValue will throw a TypeError.

The first time you enter in the cycle:

- **accumulator** is the first element
- **currentValue** is the second element

In order to lose data, you can simply change your return with an assignment:

```js
var beforeReduce = [{"name": "FrequentExtraItemID", "value": "12"},
    {"name": "ServiceType", "value": "Testing the service type"},
    {"name": "Vendor", "value": "Some vendor"},
    {"name": "Cost", "value": "100"},
    {"name": "Description", "value": "A description"},
    {"name": "ExtraServiceID", "value": "0"},
    {"name": "JobExtraID", "value": "79"}];
var beforeReduce = [{"name": "FrequentExtraItemID", "value": "12"}, {"name": "ServiceType", "value": "Testing the service type"}, {"name": "Vendor", "value": "Some vendor"}, {"name": "Cost", "value": "100"}, {"name": "Description", "value": "A description"}, {"name": "ExtraServiceID", "value": "0"}, {"name": "JobExtraID", "value": "79"}];
var afterReduce = beforeReduce.reduce(function (accumulator, currentValue, currentIndex) {
    if (currentIndex === 1) {
        var json = {};
        json[accumulator.name] = accumulator.value;
        accumulator = json;  // <---  
    }
    accumulator[currentValue.name] = currentValue.value;
    return accumulator;
});

console.log(afterReduce);
```